# R - One dimensional "Heatmap" for categorial variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, heatmap

Want to create a stack of 1D heatmaps which:

1. show the centrality (e.g. mean, represented by the *highlight*)
2. show the dispersion (e.g. standard deviation, represented by the *grading*)

Nota bene: The centrality or dispersion are not dependent on the sample sizes. The bar-length should be constant for every variable, the sample sizes are not (necessarily).

E.g. how it could look

[image]

Here a minimal example of similar variables:

```
library(plyr)

v1 <- c("yes", "rather no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "rather yes", "rather yes", "rather no", "rather no", "no", "no", "no")
(v1 <- factor(v1, levels=c("no", "rather no", "rather yes", "yes"), ordered = TRUE)) # order factor values & show
# now, one variant how to re-code/transform the _ordered_ factors as/to values
# (you may have a better proposal/oppinion)
(v1n <- sapply(v1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(mapvalues(x, from=c("no", "rather no", "rather yes", "yes"), to=c("0", "0.333", "0.666", "1")))))) # re-code to numeric & show
(v1n.mean <- mean(v1n)) # calculate mean & show
(v1n.sd   <- sd(v1n))   # calculate standard deviation & show

v2 <- c("rather yes", "rather yes", "rather no", "rather no", "rather no", "rather no", "rather no", "rather no", "rather no")
v2 <- factor(v2, levels=c("no", "rather no", "rather yes", "yes"), ordered = TRUE)
v2
v2n <- sapply(v2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(mapvalues(x, from=c("no", "rather no", "rather yes", "yes"), to=c("0", "0.333", "0.666", "1")))))
v2n
(v2n.mean <- mean(v2n))
(v2n.sd   <- sd(v2n))

v3 <- c("yes", "yes", "yes", "rather yes", "rather yes", "rather yes", "rather no", "no")
v3 <- factor(v3, levels=c("no", "rather no", "rather yes", "yes"), ordered = TRUE)
v3
v3n <- sapply(v3, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(mapvalues(x, from=c("no", "rather no", "rather yes", "yes"), to=c("0", "0.333", "0.666", "1")))))
v3n
(v3n.mean <- mean(v3n))
(v3n.sd   <- sd(v3n))
```

Comment: The continuous shading in your example picture has grading which implies a continuous variable. But your data is discrete. Do you want  to show four rectangles for each variables or do you want to treat the data as if it were continuous and show the density?

Comment: @G5W: Thank you! Yes, actually I've re-coded my variables to: -2 for "no", -1 for "rather no", 1 for "rather yes" and 2 for "yes". Here I've chosen to let the proponents to decide how to recode the data properly -- maybe someone else has a better proposal. (-:

Comment: Code indentation requires four additional spaces if you keep it in a list @alex - which means a total of 8 spaces for the first level. Alternatively, use GH style formatting with backticks.

Comment: @Zoe: As mentioned I know how to indent the code -- it simply doesn't work on my machine (have deactivated some javascript). If possible do the adjustment yourself. Thank you (-:

Comment: @alex you still had 4 spaces when you needed 8 with the list. I did fix it though. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216043/332043

Comment: Stacked barplot might be the correct solution for this kind of data

Comment: @G5W: added some code to be able to quickly recode the variables to numeric.

Comment: @PoGibas: Thank you. Actually **stacked barplots is not what I'm looking for**. The required grading -- representing to the dispersion of the data -- is not possible with barplots.

Comment: @PoGibas: ... On the other hand, barplots are representing the quantity (length of the bar), not the centrality (position on a **constant length** bar). Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to have a different number of responses for v3?

Comment: @G5W: The number of responses should not matter. The *mean* or *dispersion* (e.g. standard deviation) are not dependent on the sample size. The bar-length is constant, the samples size is not.

Comment: Another question:  Do you want the maximum value to be white and the minimum black? Or do you want 0 to be black and the maximum _possible value_ to be white? i.e. should there always be black and white, or might a bar be just gray?

Comment: @G5W: The centrality (e.g. mean) should be displayed as white and the extremities with black. Added a more precise example -- reload page and see description. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**
This answer has been updated because
1. The data v1, v2, v3 in the question has been changed and
2. labels for the three bars have been added

The upper part is still mostly the original answer. Below is a newish answer to respond to clarification from the OP.

**Original answer mostly**
Here is something like what you are asking for. However, it *cannot* show a central tendency where none exists. After we look at the graphs,  I will discuss that a bit more fully.  After we look at the graphs,  I will discuss that a bit more fully.

The idea is to make a blank plot and then draw a grayscale bar for each variable (v1, v2, v3). The place on the graph with the lowest number of responses will be black. The area with the most responses will be white. In between, the gray level will be scaled proportionally to the number of responses.

```
## To make it easy to refer to the different variables
Responses = list(v1,v2,v3)

## 100 colors to allow for a lot of continuity
## color 1 is black, color 100 is white
GrayScale = gray.colors(100, start=0.05, end=0.97)

## Make a blank plot
plot(NULL, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n",
    xlim=c(1,4), ylim=c(1,length(Responses)+1))

## Plot all of the bars
for(j in 1:length(Responses)) {
    Tab = table(Responses[[j]])
    Tab = round(99*(Tab-min(Tab))/(max(Tab)-min(Tab)))+1
    x = seq(1,4,0.01)
    Density = round(approx(1:4, Tab , x)$y)

    ## Make a smooth looking bar
    for(i in 1:(length(x)-1))  {
        polygon(c(x[i],x[i],x[i+1],x[i+1]), c(j,j+0.75,j+0.75,j), 
            col=GrayScale[Density[i]], border=NA)
    }
}
## Add labels
text(1:4, 4, levels(v1))
axis(2, at=(1:3)+0.4, labels=c("v1", "v2", "v3"), lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1, las=1)
```

[image: Barplot based on distribution of data]

**Answer to modified question**
This answer just plots Gaussian distributions using the means and standard 
deviations that you calculated. The Gaussians are plotted in the style of 
the previous answer, with white for the mean and the point most distant from 
the mean is black.

```
Means = c(v1n.mean, v2n.mean, v3n.mean)
SD    = c(v1n.sd, v2n.sd, v3n.sd)

## 100 colors to allow for a lot of continuity
## color 1 is black, color 100 is white
GrayScale = gray.colors(100, start=0.05, end=0.97)

## Make a blank plot
plot(NULL, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n",
    xlim=c(1,4), ylim=c(1,length(Responses)+1))

for(j in 1:length(Responses)) {
    x = seq(1,4,0.03)
    y = dnorm((x-1)/3, Means[j], SD[j])
    y = round(99*(y-min(y))/(max(y)-min(y))) + 1

    for(i in 1:(length(x)-1))  {
        polygon(c(x[i],x[i],x[i+1],x[i+1]), c(j,j+0.75,j+0.75,j), 
            col=GrayScale[y[i]], border=NA)
    }
}
## Add labels
text(1:4, 4, levels(v1))
axis(2, at=(1:3)+0.4, labels=c("v1", "v2", "v3"), lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1, las=1)
```

[image: Barplot from Gaussians]

Comment: Thank you -- really nice! I've added better examples. Please notice that I'm interested to display only the *mean* and *standard deviation*. It is not important how the distribution actually is (even if your example is pretty pleasing -- **please keep it** as an alternative variation possiblity for others!).

Comment: Can you please add "v1", "v2", "v3" on the left side of the graph. Thank you.

Comment: Will add mean, sd, and variable names

Comment: Thank you, really nice (-: Is it possible to rotate the labels on the vertical axis; and add ticks to the horizontal axis.